# Why is this not a valid, chained function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#infoBox").hide(, function(){
            alert('hidden!');
        });
```

Just a small question, but my code breaks when I try to do this -

Comment: You need to fill all the arguments. Try calling the method with `null` of `function(){}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot simply omit the first parameter. You need to supply a value for it e.g.:

```
$("#infoBox").hide('slow', function(){
    alert('hidden!');
});
```

See the [API page](http://api.jquery.com/hide) for information on what available values there are for the first parameter (duration).

Answer (score 3):

change this to

```
$("#infoBox").hide('slow', function(){
            alert('hidden!');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will work out what do do if you omit the speed argument in this case

```
$( "#infoBox" ).hide( function() {
    alert( 'hidden!' );
});
```